# How to get mod_wsgi-express from pip using Dockerfile

Tags: python, docker, mod-wsgi

I can't recall how I installed mod_wsgi-express, but I'm almost certain that I used `pip`.

I've got this line in my requirements.txt file:
mod_wsgi-express==4.5.15

```
Collecting mod_wsgi-express==4.5.15 (from -r /usr/src/app/requirements.txt (line 16))
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mod_wsgi-express==4.5.15 (from -r /usr/src/app/requirements.txt (line 16)) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for mod_wsgi-express==4.5.15 (from -r /usr/src/app/requirements.txt (line 16))
You are using pip version 9.0.0, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Is the naming different here? Or am I just not seeing that package?

```
$ pip list | grep mod
mod-wsgi (4.5.15)
mod-wsgi-httpd (2.4.23.2)
```

Comment: Usually you should not use ``mod_wsgi-httpd``, which is going to install a separate Apache instance from source code. Rely on your operating system Apache packages instead. Your would need both runtime and dev Apache packages from operating system package repository to be installed before doing ``pip install mod_wsgi``.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Is there a list of those specific Apache packages somewhere? I just got an error related to `apxs` and I saw an issue in github where you handled this is some other context. Could you please LMK if you know which specific Apache packages are needed, or where I can find that?

Comment: See https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mod_wsgi as it explains what packages you need when installing it.

Comment: BTW. Don't use Alpine base images. Apache crashes when using it. They are not reliable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In requirements.txt: `mod_wsgi==4.5.15`

The package information can be found on PyPi at:

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mod_wsgi

Comment: why is it that when I run this and it gets installed, I cannot find an executable for mod_wsgi in my docker container? I've ran things like `find / | grep mod_wsgi` and I only see `/usr/bin/mod_wsgi-express`